NPS India | If My Tier 1 valuation is less than 2.5 lakhs, and age less than 60, how is the NPS premature exit taxed?
I want to exit from my NPS account, Current valuation is 1.5 Lakhs.
Total Age of my account is 4.8 years. I want to exit the NPS. (Either now or at completing 5 years)
If Total invested is 94k which got now to 1.5lakh
I want to know my tax implications.
Note: lakh means 100,000 and the valuations are stated in Indian Rupees (INR)
